# Generics Type and subtype Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

Is there a way to do something like this without having to specify two generic parameters?

```
open abstract class test<Z: ClassZ, T: ClassT<Z>> {
    lateinit var varZ : Z
    lateinit var varT : T
}
```

For example, I'd like to write something like this (which doesn't compile):

```
open abstract class test<T: ClassT<Z: ClassZ>> {
    lateinit var varZ : Z
    lateinit var varT : T
}
```

Comment: Because it's not valid syntax, the code doesn't communicate the intent. You will need to explain more about what the problem is you are trying to solve. Feels like an http://xyproblem.info